# Resolution of identity for the multiplication operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I'm starting my studies in spectral theory and my professor tells me that I should study the resolution of identity. I thought I understood the theory, but when  I arrive at the examples ... I can't understand them.
So I really appreciate if someone helps me with this:

> Consider the self-adjoint operator  $\mathcal{M}_ \varphi $  wherw $\varphi : E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ acting in $L^2 _\mu (E) $ the function:
>
> $$\Lambda\mapsto  P(\Lambda) =  \chi_{\varphi^{-1} (\Lambda)} $$ is a resolution of identity. Where $\Lambda$ is a set in the Borel Algebra.

Well, for that I understood,  this is the resolution associated with multiplication operator, is this correct? If this is correct, how can I create a resolution identity associate with an operator? Does it exist a hint?

Second thing: The book says

> If $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$  is a borel function, then $f \mathcal{M}_ \varphi = \mathcal{M}_{f \circ \varphi}.$

How I get it? Using mathematical operations and the theory, how I see this?

Comment: Is $\chi$ supposed to be the characteristic function of the set $\Lambda$?

Comment: @mikestone yes. It is.

Comment: "how can I create a resolution identity associate with an operator?Does it exist a hint? " Existence is the spectral theorem for self adjoint operators. Constructing it is not trivial in general. Quantum mechanics texts construct some examples such as the harmonic oscillator and hydrogen atom.

Comment: Do you know the spectral theory in finite dimensions?

Comment: I know the spectral Theorem. But I thought "must exist something like a formula or an algorithm".  Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 1):

The intuition for the spectral measure for a densely-defined, self-adjoint, linear operator $A : \mathcal{D}(A)\subseteq\mathcal{H}\rightarrow\mathcal{H}$ on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ is that
$$
                  A dE(\lambda)=\lambda dE(\lambda).
$$
This is an "infinitesimal" equality that really only has meaning within the context of the spectral integral:
$$
              \int_{\mathbb{R}}dE(\lambda) = I, \\
               A=  A\int_{\mathbb{R}}dE(\lambda)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\lambda dE(\lambda).
$$
For $\mu\notin\mathbb{R}$, the resolvent $R(\mu)=(\mu I-A)^{-1}$ is defined, and can be written in terms of the spectral integral as
$$
            R(\mu)=\frac{1}{\mu I-A}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{\mu-\lambda}dE(\lambda).
$$
This leads to an inversion integral to construct the spectral measure from the resolvent of the self-adjoint $A$:
$$
       s\mbox{-}\lim_{v\downarrow 0} \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{(u-iv)I-A}-\frac{1}{(u+iv)I-A}du \\
       = s\mbox{-}\lim_{v\downarrow 0}\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{a}^{b}\frac{v}{(uI-A)^2+v^2}du \\
       = s\mbox{-}\lim_{v\downarrow 0}\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{a}^{b}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{v}{(u-\lambda)^2+v^2}dE(\lambda) du\\
       = s\mbox{-}\lim_{v\downarrow 0}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{\pi}\int_a^b\frac{vdu}{(u-\lambda)^2+v^2}dE(\lambda) \\
       = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{2}(\chi_{[a,b]}+\chi_{(a,b)})dE(\lambda)
       = \frac{1}{2}(E[a,b]+E(a,b))
$$
The "s-" is because the integrals converge in the strong operator topology, meaning that the limits exist when you apply the expressions to a vector and then compute the above limits. This is the Herglotz inversion formula for the constructive determination of the spectral measure from the resolvent function of a self-adjoint operator $A$.